# When running command "curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -" I get errors about permission being denied

Tags: linux

I'm trying to host a discord bot on my linux VM and part of the process is to run `curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -` after which i install NodeJS. However, when i run `curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -` I get this back

```
## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 16.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
Error executing command, exiting
```

I have tried running it like `sudo curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -` but that doesn't help.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to put the `sudo` in front of the `bash` command; try

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo bash
```